# Retrieve single record in eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Help me little please. I can't filtering single record. May be or not.

```
// In Controller
public function show(Post $post)
{
    $post = Post::with(['comments' => function($query) {
      $query->where('status', 'active');
    }
   ])->find($post);
    // can't filter comments

    return view('post.show', ['post' => $post]);
}
```

Sort comments by active

Comment: what is `sort` value?

Comment: I wrote your answer but it is important to know that post type in your controller is working or not! I assumed that `public function show(Post $post)` will return the right post and wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Read docs https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships!**

First of all, you have **`Post` type filtered as `$post`**. Just add other thing dynamically to that and finally fetch the result. You don't have to find it again!

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    $post_res = $post->with(['comments' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('status', 'asc');
    }])->get();

    return view('post.show', ['post' => $post_res]);
}
```

If your function in controller just **accepts ID as argument**, you simply can change your code to:

```
public function show(int $post_id)
{
    $post_res = Post::find($post_id)->with(['comments' => function($query) {
          $query->orderBy('status', 'asc');
      }])->get();

    return view('post.show', ['post' => $post_res]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use whereHas(),

```
$post = Post::with('comments')->whereHas('comments', function ($q) {
          $q->where('status', 'active');
        })
->find($post);
```